# How to create a lag year variable in Amazon Athena Environment using SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

How can I  generate a table from wide to long with some specific conditions?

[image: This is my original data, each id has three columns, year is their index year and y-1 is the year prior to the index year, y-2 is 2 years prior to the index year, each id only has 1 row]

Then I wish to reshape the table, from wide to long, make only a variable named year, a index year, with previous year and 2 years prior to the index year but with one more condition. I would like to expand the year moving forward to year 2021 for each bene_id. Something like below.

This is what I am looking for..:

[image: This is what I am looking for..]

Can anyone give me some advice?

I use below codes but still got wrong table..
note: I generate the codes in Amazon Athena

```sql
  WITH RECURSIVE YearSequence(bene_id, Year) AS (
    SELECT bene_id, year
    FROM tablea 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ts.bene_id, YearSequence.Year - 1
    FROM YearSequence
    JOIN tablea  AS ts ON YearSequence.bene_id = ts.bene_id
    WHERE YearSequence.Year > 2016 
  )
  SELECT bene_id, Year
  FROM YearSequence
  WHERE Year <= 2021
  ORDER BY bene_id, Year
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use recursive here, [`sequence`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#sequence) + [`unnest`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) should do the trick. Assuming that `y` (`y-2` in you data) is always the "start" year something like the following:

```sql
-- sample data, a bit simplified
with dataset(id, year, y) as(
    values ('A', 2018, 2017),
           ('B', 2019, 2018)
)

-- query
select id, t.year
from dataset,
     unnest(sequence(y, 2021)) as t(year); -- or sequence(year-2, 2021) for your case
```

Output:

| id | year |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2017 |
| A | 2018 |
| A | 2019 |
| A | 2020 |
| A | 2021 |
| B | 2018 |
| B | 2019 |
| B | 2020 |
| B | 2021 |

Comment: Hello Sir, thank you for the quick reply. However, I still encounter difficulty. In the code you provide, it only has y (the year prior to the index year), if I want to follow up to year 2 year prior, how can I modify your code ?

Comment: @MAY 1) the change is minimal and you should be able to make it yourself 2) the answer explains that you actually need only one of the 3 columns (the `Y-2` one, use it in your query instead of `y` in the answer).

Comment: @MAY also if you want 2 years prior the value of `year` column, then use `sequence(year - 2, 2021)` and that's it, no need for `Y-1` and `Y-2`

Comment: Thank you so much and it works!! Thank you for your willing to help!